# Text index ignored in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I've created a text index in MongoDB. Here is the result of getIndexes() :

```
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "test.declarations"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_fts" : "text",
            "_ftsx" : 1
        },
        "name" : "etiquettes_text_createur_text",
        "ns" : "test.declarations",
        "weights" : {
            "createur" : 1,
            "etiquettes" : 1
        },
        "default_language" : "english",
        "language_override" : "language",
        "textIndexVersion" : 3
    }
]
```

I'm using PHP and MongoDB\Driver\Manager :

```php
function declarationsLecture($filtre, $options)
{
    try {
        // On cherche dans la table des membres avec le filtre en input
        $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        $rqt = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filtre, $options);
        $resultats = $manager->executeQuery("leibnizdream.declarations", $rqt);
        return $resultats;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    ecrireFic($e->getMessage());
        return ERREUR;
    }
}
```

Filter & options:

```php
$filtre = [ '$text' => ['$search' => 'not'], ]; 
$options = [ 'projection' => ['score' => ['$meta' => 'textScore']], 'sort' => ['score' => ['$meta' => 'textScore']] ];
```

But I get the following error : text index required for $text query

Does someone understand why?

Comment: Could you include the query and options being passed to MongoDB in your question?

Comment: $filtre = [
        '$text' => ['$search' => 'not'],
    ];

    $options = [
        'projection' => ['score' => ['$meta' => 'textScore']],
        'sort' => ['score' => ['$meta' => 'textScore']]
    ];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text index is on a different collection from the one being queried.

The index is on `test.declarations` (see `"ns" : "test.declarations"`), whereas the query is being issued against either the `leibnizdream` database, or a collection named `leibnizdream.declarations` in the target database.

Comment: Right ! I had forgotten to specify the name of the database in the Mongo shell. Thanks !